# numpy dtype in membership test gives weird results

Tags: python, numpy

While writing some program involving numpy, I found that membership test doesn't work as expected for numpy dtype objects. Specifically, the result is unexpected for `set`, but not `list` or `tuple`.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(5).dtype
y = np.int64
print(x in {y}, x in (y,), x in [y])
```

the result is `False True True`.

found this in both Python 2.7 and 3.6, with numpy 1.12.x installed.

Any idea why?

**UPDATE**

looks that dtype objects don't respect some assumptions about hashing in Python.

http://www.asmeurer.com/blog/posts/what-happens-when-you-mess-with-hashing-in-python/

and https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5345

Thanks @ser2357112 and @Fabien

Comment: Related / Dupe:  [Why do these dtypes compare equal but hash different?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35293672/674039) / [Making an object x such that “x in \[x\]” returns False](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29692140/674039)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__hash__` and `__eq__` implementations of dtype objects were pretty poorly thought out. Among other problems, the `__hash__` and `__eq__` implementations aren't consistent with each other. You're seeing the effects of that here.

Some other problems with dtype `__hash__` and `__eq__` are that

- dtype objects are actually mutable in ways that affect both `__hash__` and `__eq__`, something that should never be true of a hashable object. (Specifically, you can reassign the `names` of a structured dtype.)
- dtype equality isn't transitive. For example, with the `x` and `y` in your question, we have `x == y` and `x == 'int64'`, but `y != 'int64'`.
- dtype `__eq__` raises `TypeError` when it should return `NotImplemented`.

You could submit a bug report, but looking at [existing bug reports](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5345) relating to those methods, it's unlikely to be fixed. The design is too much of a mess, and people are already relying on the broken parts.

Comment: thanks! no idea how messy numpy internal is until really looking at it...

Answer (score 0):

The difference lies in how `sets` implement the `in` keyword in Python.

> Lists simply examine each object, checking for equality. Sets first hash the objects.
>
> [*different meaning of the 'in' keyword for sets and lists*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9255474/6654077)

This is because sets must ensure uniqueness. But your objects are not equivalent:

```
>>> x
dtype('int64')
>>> y
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Hashing them probably delivers different results.

Comment: thanks. I looked at some other sources on this, like http://www.asmeurer.com/blog/posts/what-happens-when-you-mess-with-hashing-in-python/ seems that numpy implemented hash functions for dtype objects poorly?

Comment: According to [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293672/why-do-these-dtypes-compare-equal-but-hash-different), "looks like np.dtype does not define any special hash method, it just inherits from object.", so yeah... `in list({})` will do you the job, `__equal__()` seems to work ok